# Android: AlertDialog not updating the message while in Firebase ValueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, android-alertdialog

I have an alertdialog and I want to update the text while downloading my data from Firebase.

this code works perfectly counting its number and updating the message (already tested):

```
processingCount ++;
updateAlertProcessingMessage("Processando: " + processingCount);
```

However it does not work if i call it INSIDE a Firebase ValueEventListener like this example:

```
ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseReferenceUsuarios()
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snap) {
                        if (snap.exists()){
                            for (final DataSnapshot usuarioID: snap.getChildren()){
                                processingCount ++;
                                updateAlertProcessingMessage("Processando: " + processingCount);
...
```

I saw that it just update this message when the Firebase processing is over. So how to solve this?

Comment: So what's the problem with this code?

Comment: AlertDialog message is not updated until Firebase finishes it porcessing. By the code u can see that the update line is INSIDE a ValueEventListener. So this should not happen